# Getting download URL for Firebase Storage for Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

```
ref: AngularFireStorageReference;
task: AngularFireUploadTask;
uploadState: Observable<string>;
uploadProgress: Observable<number>;
downloadURL: Observable<string>;

upload(event) {
  const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  this.ref = this.afStorage.ref(id);
  this.task = this.ref.put(event.target.files[0]);
  this.uploadState = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(s => s.state));
  this.uploadProgress = this.task.percentageChanges();
  this.downloadURL = this.task.downloadURL();
}
```

Above is from [guide](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/firebase-cloud-storage-with-angular-394566fd529).

I expect this to get the download URL once upload is completed to firebase storage. But I get this error:

> TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
upload(event) {
  const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const filePath = id;
  this.ref = this.afStorage.ref(id);
  this.task = this.afStorage.upload(filePath, file);
  this.uploadState = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(s => s.state));
  this.uploadProgress = this.task.percentageChanges();
  this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = this.ref.getDownloadURL() )
  ).subscribe()
}
```